# iOS Localize Splash Screen in Xcode 4.6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, splash-screen

I found a bug in Xcode 4.6 during the App Store submission process.

The problem is from May 1, 2013, Apple reject applications that doesn't support retina display and iPhone 5.
To understand if an application is optimized for iPhone 5 the process looks into the launch image section in the settings:

[image]

The problem born when you try to localize the splash screen: to localize splash screen you must drag the image NOT in the launch images section, but in the **supporting file** folder in project navigator. Then localize the image and call it Default.png (and with other appropriate name for iPhone 5 and iPad). This procedure cause the launch images sections are blank even if all works fine: in the device you can see the correct splash based on device language.

But, because Apple looks into this section to understand if an app is optimized for iPhone 5 you can't able to publish the app and the process returns you this error: **iPhone 5 optimization required**.

This is a bug in Xcode because the process I mentioned works fine...
Has anyone have encountered this problem and found a solution to it?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

please check this:

"....you can also localize your application icons and ***launch images*** by placing files with the same name in your language-specific project directories. ***Even if you provide localized versions***, however, ***you should always include a default version of these files at the top-level*** of your application bundle. The default version is used in situations where a specific localization is not available..." from [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I have solved it using `UILaunchImageFile` key in the app `Info.plist` and renaming the splash images, check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12) for a more complete explanation

Comment: your answer isnt very full, please add detail