# Splash screen in multi-language iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, splash-screen

I am working on an app which is in 12 languages. Each language will have different splash screen. I have tried almost all possible ways to add splash screen images (Default.png) and it is working fine in all the cases. But, when I try to upload it on App store, it is giving me below error(attaching screenshot):- 
[image: Error at the time of validating the app]
 After that, I tried other possible solutions, but none of them worked for me. The main problem is showing in below image:- 
 
[image: Launch images]
 
When I try to select any image from browse pop-up, it won't display in above list and displays same message ("No image specified"). I have added all the images in my bundle.
 [image: Images added in the bundle] 
Could anyone please guide me where I am doing mistake?
Note:- I am using Xcode 5.1.

Comment: Are you sure you can localize images? Have you tried that before?

Comment: I followed this tutorial:- http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/

Comment: That's good to know, thanks. Then the problem is definitely not with the localization.

Comment: @SergiusGee Thanks for prompt reply. I really don't know what & where the problem is?

Comment: @PiyushDubey first update your xcode version from xcode 5.1 to xcode 5.1.1

Comment: @Sudha Why? That doesn't seem to add to the conversation, maybe if you added why then it possibly would help more.

Comment: @Popeye Last week I am also trying to upload the project on app store and getting some issues because of only xcode lowest version.

Comment: @Sudha that helps a lot more then just upgrade from version 5.1 to version 5.1.1

Comment: maybe … a “default version”…? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17625006

Comment: @TonyMkenu I tried this also, but each time "Default" image (which is in English language) is launching.

Comment: Thanks this is still working for me but i am facing once issue. When i switch Device Language  after installing app splash didn't localize as per language. I mean this is just working for fresh app install. can you please help me how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 5):

Here's how to localize your Launch.xib screen:

1. Create `InfoPlist.strings` file. (File,New,Resource,Strings)
2. Localize it and select your languages
3. For e.g. the Spanish version, add your launch screen key and name for the Spanish version of your Launch screen

   `"UILaunchStoryboardName" = "Launch_es";`
4. Copy your existing Launch.xib to Launch_es.xib, and change the text and/or images to the Spanish translations or Spanish-named images.

Answer (score 4):

This addresses the problem.
[Is there a way to have a different Default.png (splash image) for different languages/locales in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10570757/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-different-default-png-splash-image-for-different-lang)

Pretty much put different images in each localization folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I fixed it by renaming all the splash images (eg: iphone_5_en, iphone_5_it, etc...) and thent I localized the infoPlist.strings file.
In the infoPlist.strings file i changed the value of the splash image keys UILaunchImageFile and UILaunchImageFile~ipad.

Comment: My app is universal app and is in 12 languages. iPad app is in both orientation. So, do you think it is feasible to rename around 100+ images? Can't I go with any other way?

Comment: How did you even get this to work if you renamed the images something like iphone_5_en? The launch images have to be named `Default.png` etc.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases when you want to localize your app for one of the languages, you could use localized InfoPlist.strings. Note the name is case sensitive!

[image: InfoPlist.strings]

You could create this file InfoPlist.strings -> localize -> change languages.

Inside of this file for each localization you could add next Localizable properties:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "AppName";    
"CFBundleName" = "AppName";  
"UILaunchStoryboardName" = "Launch Screen";
```

localized:

```
"CFBundleDisplayName" = "arAppName";      
"CFBundleName" = "arAppName";   
"UILaunchStoryboardName" = "Launch Screen_ar";
```

When the app launches, this data will be used for the launch screen and app name properties.

```
"UILaunchStoryboardName" = "Launch Screen_arabic";
```

After that, you can create arLaunchScreen, enLaunchScreen, etc.